# Create a new file everyday

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app that loops for several hours or even maybe days and what I want is that it loops past the current day into the next it creates a new file with a new file name.
Can anyone help me with the logic ?
Here is my code:

```
    timedata= new File(timedata)
    String timedatafile=  "/sdcard/timedata"+"-"+formattedDate+".csv";

    if(MsureData.exists()!=true)
{
    timedata.createNewFile();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime()); 
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having? What is the expected result? What is the result you are seeing? How do they differ?

Comment: Basicly the file name is timedata-2014-05-06  and it turns into a new day at 00:00 I want it to create a new file named timedata-2014-05-07

Comment: Save the current date in a variable and include `c.getTime()` in the loop, when it differs from the current date just replace the value in the variable and create a new file.

Answer (score 0):

Save the current date in a variable and include c.getTime() in the loop, when it differs from the current date just replace the value in the variable and create a new file.

```
//new date object initialized to current date
Date currentDate = new Date(); 
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
//loop indefinately
while(true){
    if(!c.getTime().equals(currentDate)){
        //create a new file and set the current date
        currentDate = c.getTime();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You still aren't providing enough context. The code you posted doesn't even compile.

- `formatedDate` is defined after being used
- You use `timedata` as both the argument to the `File` constructor and the resulting new instance. There is no `File` constructor that takes a single `File` instance ([Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#constructor.summary)).

However, based on what you have, I would guess that:

You are not making a new `File` instance once you determine a new one must be created. You create the `timedata` instance and calling `createNewFile()` before you are getting the new date. Once you have determined the date you want to use, only then can you create the `File` instance and create the file. Just updating the value in `formattedDate` will not change the file name of the already existing `File` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you write measure data to the csv file calculate the current filename and use that.

Assuming you have some kind of service which is called every now and then by a timer or similar, the entry point for that is `onSomeEvent` which figures out which file to use and then does something to it.

```
class Writer extends SomeService {
    File current = null;
    DateFormat df = ...;

    public void onSomeEvent() {
        determineCurrentFile();
        // you can be sure that this file exists and it may or may not contain data already,
        // but for sure it is for the current date (today)
        AnotherClass.doSomethingWithMyFile(current);
    }

    private void determineCurrentFile() {
        File newFile = new File(getFileName());
        if(current == null) { // first usage
            current = newFile;
        } else if(!this.current.equals(newFile)) {
            current = newFile; // new day (doesn't matter how many days passed)
        } else {
            // same day, don't touch current
        }
        ensureFileExists(); // not sure if needed, I would let whoever writing it do the creation
    }

    private String getFileName() {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
        return formattedDate;
    }

    private void ensureFileExists() {
        if(current == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("determineFile should have filled this.current");
        }
        if(!current.exists()) {
            current.createNewFile();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Quartz API](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) to schedule a job to be executed at a specific time. See these tutorials-http://www.mkyong.com/java/quartz-scheduler-example/

Answer (score 0):

```
int yourdelay=86400000; // delay in millisecond, 24 hours=86400000 millisecond

final Handler handler = new Handler();

handler.post(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
       Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
       SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",Locale.getDefault());
       String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());

       String pathfile=  "/sdcard/timedata"+"-"+formattedDate+".csv";
       File filedata= new File(pathfile);

       //if file not exists create new file
       if(!filedata.exists())
       {
          filedata.createNewFile();                

       }

      handler.postDelayed(this, yourdelay);

    }
});
```

***This one form to solve your problem implementing handler to run day by day in the same hour minute and second.***

Comment: FYI, if any chance that file will reach a Mac OS X or iOS computer, then replace the illegal colon characters in the time portion of that file name. Not allowed in the [HFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus) file system.

Answer (score -1):

```
Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

From this you can get current date of system.

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: I get the time and date from c.gettime

Comment: what exactly you want ? You want to create new file at regular intervals & its date should be current date ?